# error while reading a text file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file

```
def read_file_info(*file_name)
  arr = IO.readlines(file_name)
  puts arr
end

read_file_info("abcd.txt")
```

is giving me an error in

```
readlines': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 5):

`*file_name` means variable amount of parameters, you would need to extract the first parameter with `file_name[0]`, check the other answer for single parameter or use multiple files:

```
def read_file_info(*files)
  files.each do |file_name|
    arr = IO.readlines(file_name)
    puts arr
  end
end

read_file_info("abcd.txt", "efgh.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it as:

```
def read_file_info(file_name)
  arr = IO.readlines(file_name)
  puts arr
end

read_file_info("abcd.txt")
```

This is what happened when you pass `"abcd.txt"` to the method. `*file_name` creates an array:

```
def read_file_info(*file_name)
  p file_name
end

read_file_info("abcd.txt")
# >> ["abcd.txt"]
```

`IO.readlines(file_name)` expects a single file name as a string, but you gave it an `Array`, which, in turn, gave you the error:

```
no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)
```

If you want to use `*file_name` then, inside the method, use [`Array#[]`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#%5B%5D-instance_method) to give your `IO.readlines` method a single file at a time as a string.